# Как использовать NSUserDefaults для хранения класса из двух строковых полей?

Tags: nsuserdefaults, storage, objective-c, классы

Есть класс с двумя полями типа **`NSString`**. Как сохранить несколько (поочерёдно, т. е., не одним разом) его объектов в *`NSUserDefaults`*?

---

#### UPD:

Правильно ли будет читать из ключа массив, добавлять в него объект, а потом перезаписывать ключ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Массив не сработает, NSUserDefaults умеет сохранять только NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate + словари и массивы из них, ну и простые типы наподобия int конечно.

Свой класс в общем виде можно сохранить в массив упаковав его в `NSData` через `[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:myObject];`, в вашем классе должен быть метод - `(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder`, соответственно есть парные методы для распаковки.

Но конкретно в вашем случае  мне кажется проще перекинуть класс в словарь:

```
NSDictionary dictionary=[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:myObj.field1,@"field1", myObj.field2,@"field2",nil];
```

и уже эти словари упаковать в массив

Comment: @aknew, NSUserDefaults имеет метод «[setObject](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSUserDefaults/setObject:forKey:)»

А любой массив будет являться объектом.

Comment: Ну так если вы знаете про этот метод может вы его описание прочитаете в справке:The value parameter can be only property list objects: NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. For NSArray and NSDictionary objects, their contents must be property list objects

Comment: > Но конкретно в вашем случае мне кажется проще перекинуть класс в словарь

В каком смысле? 

----- 

> Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.

Comment: подправил ответ, исхожу из того что поля NSString как вы и описали, по сути это то же архивирование